# preg_match_all error when pattern is a variable in YII

Tags: php, yii

I have a table called dictionary, in which has words that want to find in a text being pulled from another table. I'm using preg_match_all to match the words in the text. I have tried many different solutions that found online, but no luck so far. It seems that the problem is when I create a variable $pattern to hold the text, please see code below. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
  <?php $words=  Dictionary::model()->findAllBySql("select word from tbl_dictionary ");?> <?php foreach ($words as $word): ?>

        <?php  //$matches = array()?>
        <?php  $string =$data->text_content; $pattern = "/\b($string)\b/" ; preg_match('.$pattern.', $word->word, $match);?>

         <?php echo var_dump($match); ?>


         <?php endforeach  ;?>
```

Comment: Your pattern is in single quotes, `'.$pattern.'` so it is literally `$pattern`. Also periods as delimiters are strange and I'm not sure would work. If it does you'll loose the functionally of `.` as meaning any character. Also `$string` is only words? Could it have any special regex characters in it ever?

Comment: I don't think there were period in pattern, I've used like this '/\b(' . $data->text_content. '/' . ')\b/i', and still did not work

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but your preg_match should be `preg_match(".$pattern.", $word->word, $match);`. See the double quote usage so the variable is interrupted.

Comment: I did it and got the following error "preg_match(): Unknown modifier '&lt;'"

Comment: There must be a period and &lt; after it in your `$pattern` in that case.

Comment: I was doing the wrong way round. The variable $pattern should have the words I was looking for and where $word->word was should be $data->text_content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it the wrong way round. The variable $pattern should have the words I was looking for and where $word->word was should be
$data->text_content. Only purified $data->text_content

```
<?php $words=  Dictionary::model()->findAllBySql("select word from tbl_dictionary ");?>

       <?php foreach ($words as $word): ?>



        <?php  //$matches = array()

                        $CHtmlPurifier = new CHtmlPurifier();
                         $CHtmlPurifier->options = array('HTML.ForbiddenElements' => array('br, p, img,&lt'));
                        $purified = $CHtmlPurifier->purify($data->text_content);

            preg_match( "/$word->word/", $purified, $match);


         ?>  
         <?php echo var_dump($match); ?>
```